# Changein javaScript variable is temporary, how to i make it permanent. Console log is attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made changes to p tag and only one of the p changed.
Later again I tried displaying the change but the change was not seen.

Here's what I'm doing:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var html = "<div> <p></p> <p></p> <p></p> </div>";

  //making some changes to <p> tag

  $(html).find('p').each(function (){
    $(this).text("SomeText");
    console.log($(this).text());
  });

  // now again display the changes
  $(html).find('p').each(function (){
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>(Look in the console for the result.)</div>
```

Comment: It is because you html variable is still the same, and all p tags are empty :)

Comment: That's what. How do i make the changes to html variable ? Thanks

Comment: By passing `html` to jQuery like so: `$(html)` you're generating a new object. That means that you're creating two different jQuery objects with the same markup. Create a reference, i.e. `var elm = $(html);` and use `elm.find('p')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you are creating jquery object from `html` each time. You need to save your modified object if you need retain your progress.

Try that:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var html = "<div> <p></p> <p></p> <p></p> </div>";

           //making some changes to <p> tag
           var jHtml = $(html);
           jHtml.find('p').each(function (){
            $(this).text("SomeText");
                console.log($(this).text());
          });

          // now again display the changes
           jHtml.find('p').each(function (){
             console.log($(this).text());
         });
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4mLsh1/)

Comment: "Try that" answers are not useful. Say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder absolutely agree. I am doing that little trick in order to get answer faster and than I am modifying that to look better and adding come explanations with links and etc. hope that is not too wrong.

Comment: @KaNcH so you say only one p tag changed? I can see in console 3 same outputs. See alert http://jsfiddle.net/jj4mLsh1/1/

Comment: @Vladimirs: Don't post incomplete answers just to be sooner. It is indeed inappropriate, and besides, consider what you leave lying around if your internet connection goes down, or SO goes down, or you get called away, or...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well by giving fast answer I am kinda saying to others that I am already working on that so that new people that started to look at that question won't start typing answer if they will see that my answer is correct (even if not ideally formatted and described). So they won't spend time on that but will have a chance to help others. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Vladimirs: Nonetheless, it is inappropriate. It's not how things are done here. Post complete answers, not incomplete ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save somewhere your changed HTML. In DOM for example or in variable:

```
//making some changes to <p> tag
var newHTML = $(html).find('p').each(function (){
```

and then

```
// now again display the changes
$(newHTML).find('p').each(function (){
```

Or just create jQuery HTML object:

```
var html = $("<div> <p></p> <p></p> <p></p> </div>");
```

and use it in your methods:

```
html.find('p').each(
// etc
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var html = $("<div> <p></p> <p></p> <p></p> </div>");

  //making some changes to <p> tag

  html.find('p').each(function (){
    $(this).text("SomeText");
    console.log($(this).text());
  });

  // now again display the changes
  html.find('p').each(function (){
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>(Look in the console for the result.)</div>
```